# Bring up html file from sheets using apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a google sheet that when you pick something on a google sheet it brings up an html file on a new google tab that has info from the google sheet.  I am using the code below as a quick test to see if this is possible.

Right now I have a menu item that calls myFunction(), then I would like that to bring up the new html page.  This doesn't come close to working, as it just enters and exits myFunction and no html page. So was wondering if anyone knows if this is possible. If so can you give me some hints on how to do it.

code.gs

```
function myFunction(){ 
   HtmlService.createTemplate('page');
};
```

page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <title>Hello<\title>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `myFunction()` to `doGet()`, and you need to return the HtmlService from the doGet function. Also, the statement inside the `doGet()` function is different than what you currently have.

Your myFunction() function should look like this

```
 function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page').evaluate();
}
```

doGet() is a special function that Google Apps Script web app scripts should handle any GET requests.

---

For more information, please refer to one of these guides:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html

Answer (score 0):

#### This is absolutely possible.

What you want to implement is a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

#### Simple Example

```js
function doGet() {
    textOutput = ContentService.createTextOutput("Hello World! Welcome to the web app.")
    return textOutput
}
```

Put this in a script file and then *deploy* the script as a web app - [instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app). The deploy process will give you a link with which you can visit the web app and see your text output.

What apps script does is that every time someone visits the URL, the `doGet` function is run.

#### HTML Example

```js
function doGet(){
    let HTMLString = "<style> h1,p {font-family: 'Helvitica', 'Arial'}</style>"
                    + "<h1>Hello World!</h1>"
                    + "<p>Welcome to the Web App";
    HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);
    return HTMLOutput
}
```

As you have already seen, [`HtmlService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html) is what to use to serve up HTML.

#### Linking to Spreadsheet

The best way IMO to approach this is:

- Create a spreadsheet.
- Create the script *from the spreadsheet menu* - this ensures that the script and sheet are linked.
- Decide how you want to present the information from the Spreadsheet and get it with something like:

  ```js
  let file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // getActive only possible if script and sheet are linked
  let sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let range = sheet.getDataRange();
  let values = range.getValues();
  ```
- Figure out how to translate that into HTML.
- Write your `doGet` function.
- Deploy
- Profit!

#### Docs

- [Google Apps Script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

Comment: I tried the following and got an error message
'We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again'
My current code:

function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuEntries = [{name: "xxx", functionName: "doGet"}];
  ss.addMenu("yyy", menuEntries);
}

function doGet()
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        let HTMLString = "<style> h1,p {font-family: 'Helvitica', 'Arial'}</style>"
                    + "<h1>Hello</h1>";
    HTMLOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(HTMLString);
    return HTMLOutput
};